# VS2010 ultimate DataBase Project + SQL Server 2008: Updating Project from Database

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, database-project

this is a quick question:

I have this Database Project in a Web app solution with the real database. I want to update the database using SQL server managment studio, and then update the corresponding VS project.

This can be done?

I know that you can update the scripts in the project, but I'm not the SQL kind of guy, i rather do this changes using Mangment studio...

Thanks in advance

**Update:** Okay, the point is that I want to make changes (if I have to) on the database, using Sql Server Managment studio, and then update the scripts in the Visual Studio DataBase Project, instead of make my updates on those scripts, because I don't feel confortable writing SQL commands. Now what I do is to recreate everytime the Database Project (delete and then create again), this is what I want to avoid

Also, I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: The question is not so clear. It would be better to have more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very achievable in VS2010 Premium and I am currently doing what you describe with a **Database Project** and a **Schema Comparison** item.

Sigd is not correct in saying you can only compare **Database/Project Compare**, you can also compare **Project / Database** and **Database / Database**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the Schema Compare feature, but this is only available with the Premium or Ultimate editions of Visual Studio, not the Professional edition.

In many cases this is possible using Red Gate SQL Compare Pro, although I should warn you that this is not a fully supported scenario just yet (I'm the product manager for this tool so I'd welcome your feedback if you go this route!).

Red Gate's SQL Source Control better fulfills your suggested way of working, although this won't help you just yet as we don't tie into VS Database Projects. Again, this is something we are considering for an upcoming release. You're welcome to try it and let us know what you think.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

If only the *Schema Compare* tool did what it's name suggests.

Unfortunately it is a "Database/Project Compare".   So my project which includes only a single schema, when compared with the database, generates loads of Create actions for all the other schema objects present in the database.

Nice idea, needs work.